# Using @typescript-eslint/naming-convention is it possible to select class properties that are not static?

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

I have the following typescript:

```
export class ConsentOptionsWidget {
  public static NULL_CATEGORY_PLACEHOLDER = 'Opt in to channel';
  public static EMAIL_CHANNEL = 'Email';
  public header_name!: string;
  public consentStatement!: string;
}
```

and my eslint rule:

```
"@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
  "error",
  {
    "format": ["snake_case"],
    "modifiers": ["public"],
    "selector": "classProperty"
  }
]
```

I only want the rule to apply to `header_name` and `consentStatement` with `consentStatement` generating an error. But, as is, `consentStatement`, `NULL_CATEGORY_PLACEHOLDER` and `EMAIL_CHANNEL` generate errors.

According to the project maintainers, even though the docs say "The name must match all of the modifiers" `modifiers` is actually a superset so `public` matches anything with `public` regardless of any other modifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another descriptor with no format requirement for public static properties.

```
"@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
  "error",
  {
    "format": ["snake_case"],
    "modifiers": ["public"],
    "selector": "classProperty"
  },
  {
    "modifiers": ["public", "static"],
    "selector": "classProperty"
  }
]
```

[**DEMO LINK**](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=4.9.3&sourceType=module&code=KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GEIDs3C4wDyYMAlnmgOrkAmA5sPAN4BQccYArgEZLkEcNDBQUhAOQCqAGRkB9LAEEAKgFEA4sQBKATXkAFGUqxqAEsRkARNdrgBeOAHJS8crjgwIiABYpcuMBITgDcHFx8AkIiYoJwagCySgCSClhmShISajIOzmoAtijkwWGcPPxxPsAodMBQ8rgoBcAAhABcwjBQ7gxlEZVCCFSEMADKojDALUQdXT24fWwAvkA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQAIBcBPABxQGNoBLY-AWhXkoDt8B6JgQwFtmBzWsgHsmAN0QtKw9GADa4bDkTRog6JAA08hVgXZIAM1VcO+aXN27IyTgGtEAfTIdkiSFt0BdTRZxdBAE0p9SiVUDHMfHGJYACNGMjdIr3cFK0QkMnxVaUgyeGdkAAUVUmgiRN0AX29dHQtIP0Dg0LMUy2i4ygSayKt8Ey6Ki2TelwystQxc-OQikqVytsr3D3llyqA&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA)